# How do I roll sensu logs without restarting?

Tags: sensu

Sensu logs can fill up with large amounts of data.  You can setup an outside infrastructure with logrotate to restart sensu software on a periodic basis to eliminate open file handles but we would prefer not to restart.

Is there a way to roll the logs to a set number of backups with a set disk usage?  I'm looking for configuration similar to how you can configure a Java application's logging with log4j and rolling file appenders/loggers.  I cannot find anything on the sensu website.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: In my case, it turned out that the PID files from `/var/run/sensu/sensu-.*.pid` were missing, which seems to be due to the fact that we're managing the Sensu processes via `/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/sensu-ctl`. I ended up fixing it by applying [this patch](https://github.com/mihaitodor/sensu-build/commit/c14707233da7045afec54b6c686a8b1a39860bce) to [logrotate.d/sensu](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-build/blob/2d4c6a4d1fd80a1cd5a71488fe3972fcac6e7065/sensu_configs/logrotate.d/sensu):

```
diff --git a/sensu_configs/logrotate.d/sensu b/sensu_configs/logrotate.d/sensu
index 8457e29..42a80f9 100644
--- a/sensu_configs/logrotate.d/sensu
+++ b/sensu_configs/logrotate.d/sensu
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@
     sharedscripts
     compress
     postrotate
-        kill -USR2 `cat /var/run/sensu/sensu-client.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
+        /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/sensu-ctl sensu-client 2
     endscript
 }

@@ -18,7 +18,7 @@
     sharedscripts
     compress
     postrotate
-        kill -USR2 `cat /var/run/sensu/sensu-server.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
+        /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/sensu-ctl sensu-server 2
     endscript
 }

@@ -30,6 +30,6 @@
     sharedscripts
     compress
     postrotate
-        kill -USR2 `cat /var/run/sensu/sensu-api.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
+        /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/sensu-ctl sensu-api 2
     endscript
 }
```

I am leaving the original answer below, in case somebody finds it useful.

---

I think [logrotate.d/sensu](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-build/blob/2d4c6a4d1fd80a1cd5a71488fe3972fcac6e7065/sensu_configs/logrotate.d/sensu) should do what you need, by sending the `-USR2` signal to Sensu when rotating logs. You might need to apply [this](https://github.com/centos-opstools/sensu/commit/1e4b6cbc2e59a1ac6abd2e929d83c5557934a383) patch to it, though:

```
diff --git a/sensu.logrotate b/sensu.logrotate
index 8457e29..a5178fa 100644
--- a/sensu.logrotate
+++ b/sensu.logrotate
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log {
+    su sensu sensu
     rotate 7
     daily
     missingok
@@ -11,6 +12,7 @@
 }

 /var/log/sensu/sensu-server.log {
+    su sensu sensu
     rotate 7
     daily
     missingok
@@ -23,6 +25,7 @@
 }

 /var/log/sensu/sensu-api.log {
+    su sensu sensu
     rotate 7
     daily
     missingok
```

Please let me know if you ever get a chance to test it out.